# PHP GnuPG Extension Not Working with Nginx, Fails to add PGP Key

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

I'm trying to use the PHP GnuPG extension to perform PGP encryption in my PHP script. The script works as expected when running with the built-in test server (php -S), but it fails to import a PGP public key when served through Nginx. I'm encountering the "Error importing public key" issue.

Here's an overview of the situation:

PHP Version: 8.1.24
Nginx Version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

```
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");

$pubkey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.2.6 (GNU/Linux)
[KEY HERE]
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----";

$enc = (null);
$res = gnupg_init();
var_dump($res);
$rtv = gnupg_import($res, $pubkey);
$rtv = gnupg_addencryptkey($res, "C25F29936D9046D73A77DCF8244F423AED8F1481");
var_dump($rtv);
$enc = gnupg_encrypt($res, "just a test to see if anything works");
var_dump($enc);
echo "Encrypted Data: " . $enc . "<br/>";
```

I tested the script with nginx and the php test server.
While using the php server I get a output like this:

```
resource(2) of type (ctx) 

array(9) { ["imported"]=> int(0) ["unchanged"]=> int(1) ["newuserids"]=> int(0) 
["newsubkeys"]=> int(0) 
["secretimported"]=> int(0) 
["secretunchanged"]=> int(0) 
["newsignatures"]=> int(0) 
["skippedkeys"]=> int(0) 
["fingerprint"]=> string(40) "C25F29936D9046D73A77DCF8244F423AED8F1481" 
} 

bool(true) 

Encrypted Data: -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- [MESSAGE]-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

But with nginx the output is only:

```
resource(2) of type (ctx) 
array(9) { 
["imported"]=> int(0) 
["unchanged"]=> int(1) 
["newuserids"]=> int(0) 
["newsubkeys"]=> int(0) 
["secretimported"]=> int(0) 
["secretunchanged"]=> int(0) 
["newsignatures"]=> int(0) 
["skippedkeys"]=> int(0) 
["fingerprint"]=> string(40) "C25F29936D9046D73A77DCF8244F423AED8F1481" } 

bool(false) 

Encrypted Data:
```

I added the line `extension = gnupg.so` to these files:

```
/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
```

I also added a file to the conf.d folder called `gnupg.ini`

I've noticed that when I run phpinfo() on the test server, there's a PATH environment variable that includes GnuPG, but this variable is not present when running the same script through Nginx.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is `gnupg_geterror()`/`gnupg_geterrorinfo()` returning, when the API call failed? Some method is returning `false` to indicate an error.

Comment: With the method `gnupg_geterrorinfo` I get the result: `no key for encryption set`

Comment: Then add an encryption key. Keep in mind to check the return value from **all** function calls, if they return `false` or not. In your code you are not checking the result of `gnupg_import()`. Also check with `gnupg_keyinfo()` which keys are available (not sure if `"*"` is working as a search string). If `import()` fail, then selecting the key might fail as well. `geterrorinfo()` might only return the *last* error message, so you should call it if one method is returning `false`.

Comment: Yes but with the function `gnupg_addencryptkey` I already added a encryption key or not?

Comment: Please check the return value of **every** function of `gnupg_*()`. If there is an error, use `gnupg_geterrorinfo()` or `gnupg_geterror()`. Please [edit] your question to include the new source code you have and the output you get when you check the error messages.